# Icon cannot be seen

Tags: html, css, styles

I'm using some font icons for my website, and downloaded font awesome correctly. The problem is I cant see the the icon on my browser. I styled the icon area in CSS and I think it may be covering the icon. The icon is Shopping cart

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post the code instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried that your icon might be overlaid, you can take a look at the z-index property. With this property you can specify which element should be on which layer.

For example:

```
.shoppingcart{
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Or you look inside the browser in the Developer Tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>) with the Inspector, if the icon exists and where it is located.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using font awesome latest version 6.1.1 , so you should change it from HTML `<link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/css/fontawesome.min.css">` and replace `<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/11449f5f4a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` this font awesome latest version script

if you seems that your icon overlayed by others element so CSS code

`.shopping-icon { z-index: 1; }`
if don't show increase the z-index value.